# TSQL - How to iterate a list of strings

Tags: t-sql, database-cursor

I want to create a procedure that will insert all my jobs to the DB.
(a. All my jobs have equal characteristics. b. SSDT doesn't support jobs code management)

Now, I thought to create a script to insert all of them and as a c# developer I thought I need to initialize a list with their names.

I discovered while googling that the way to do it is with an in memory table and the best I could come with is this.

```
declare @jobsNames table(Id int, JobName nvarchar(100))

insert into @jobsNames (Id,JobName)
    select 1,'JobName1' union
    select 2,'JobName2' union
    ......

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE JobsCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT JobName FROM @jobsNames
OPEN JobsCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM JobsCursor INTO @JobName
WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
     .. do stuff

     FETCH NEXT FROM JobsCursor INTO @JobName
     WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Question -

Is this the shortest/recommended way?
(It seems a hellotof code for a foreach)

Answer (score 5):

```
declare @jobNames table(Id int, JobName nvarchar(100))

insert @jobNames values
    (1, 'JobName1'),
    (2, 'JobName2'),
--
    (10, 'JobName10')

while exists(select 1 from @jobNames)
begin
    declare @id int, @name nvarchar(100)
    select top 1 @id = Id, @name = JobName from @jobNames
    delete from @jobNames where Id = @Id

    -- Do stuff here
end
```

Comment: It seems that should be `insert into @jobNames`, otherwise at least SQL Server outputs a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I avoid Cursors like the plague.  Please make sure that you HAVE to iterate instead of doing your work set based.  They don't call it [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) for nothing.

```
DECLARE @counter INT, @max INT

SELECT @counter = 1, @max = max(id)
FROM @jobsNames

WHILE @counter <= @max
BEGIN
    SELECT @val1 = val1 ... FROM @jobNames where ID = @counter
    -- .. do stuff
    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```